# Cast interface{} to type in template

Tags: go, go-templates

```
  Templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, "index.html", map[string]interface{} {
        "Games": games})
}
```

Where games is `[]map[string]interface{}` (mapped result of sql query)

In template:

```
{{ range $gval := .Games }} 
    {{ how to make something like: $gval.name.(string) }} 
{{end}}
```

How to cast interface{} value of map to string(or int) in template? In 'go' i can do 
`games[0]["name"].(string)`

When i do  `$gval.name` it writes hex string

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to do type assertions from a template. You'll have to write your own function and call it from the template. For example:

```
func ToString(value interface{}) string {
    switch v := value.(type) {
    case string:
        return v
    case int:
        return strconv.Itoa(v)
    // Add whatever other types you need
    default:
        return ""
    }
}
```

To be able to call the function from template you have to call the Funcs() method on your template:

```
tpl.Funcs(template.FuncMap{"tostring": ToString})
```

Now you can do `{{$gval.name | tostring}}` inside your template

Answer (score 2):

I believe accepted answer is no longer necessary. I was just able to use interface{} values without explicitly typecasting it in golang template. I am on go v1.16.

Comment: Can you add some examples or docs with your answer to provide more context for people?